# Valums Ajax File Upload works in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I'm developing in ASP.NET MVC3 and I have the the code below for saving the file in Sql Server 2008, it works well for IE (I used IE9) but in Firefox I get the error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index", how should i fix this? thanks

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(string qqfile)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
            var stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            App_MessageAttachment NewAttachment = new App_MessageAttachment
            {
                FileName = postedFile.FileName.ToString().Substring(postedFile.FileName.ToString().LastIndexOf('\\') + 1),
                FilteContentType = postedFile.ContentType,
                MessageId = 4,
                FileData = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength]
            };
            postedFile.InputStream.Read(NewAttachment.FileData, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
            db.App_MessageAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(NewAttachment);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, "application/json");
        }
        return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Valums Ajax upload has 2 modes. If it recognizes that the browser supports HTML5 File API (which undoubtedly is the case with FireFox) it uses this API instead of using an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` request. So in your controller action you need to account for those differences and in the case of modern browsers that support HTML5 read the `Request.InputStream` directly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(string qqfile)
{
    try
    {
        var stream = Request.InputStream;
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(qqfile);

        // TODO: not sure about the content type. Check
        // with the documentation how is the content type 
        // for the file transmitted in the case of HTML5 File API
        var contentType = Request.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(qqfile))
        {
            // IE
            var postedFile = Request.Files[0];
            stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
        }
        var contentLength = stream.Length;

        var newAttachment = new App_MessageAttachment
        {
            FileName = filename,
            FilteContentType = contentType,
            MessageId = 4,
            FileData = new byte[contentLength]
        };
        stream.Read(newAttachment.FileData, 0, contentLength);
        db.App_MessageAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(newAttachment);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
    }
    return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
}
```

The code might need some tweaking. I don't have time to test it right now but you get the idea: in the case of HTML5 enabled browser the file is written directly to the body of the request whereas for browsers that do not support the File API the file data is transmitted using the standard `multipart/form-data` encoding.